# Random Sorting Formula

Tags: list, sorting, math, random, formula

I have a list that is made of 3’s, 6’s, and 9’s in a random order. They are then “in order” added to by 3, then 6, then 9 in a new list. The old list is never used again. Can someone help me find a formula to get the original list back?

Original_list = [3,3,6,9,6,6,3,9]

Time = [3,6,9,3,6,9,3,6]

New_list = [6,9,6,3,3,6,6,6]

New list is in random order however time is not. Old list adds to Time. I have tried making my own formulas for solving but I can’t seem to figure out how to integrate Time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You in your example we can see addition work like this:

```
3 + 3 = 6
3 + 6 = 9
6 + 6 = 3
6 + 9 = 6
9 + 3 = 3
9 + 6 = 6
```

It is not hard to gues the other 3 entries in the addition table.

So to get from the "new" list back to the "original" list, all we have to do is apply subtraction:

```
6 - 3 = 3
9 - 6 = 3
3 - 6 = 6
6 - 9 = 6
3 - 3 = 9
6 - 6 = 9
```

and so on.

Comment: Niether of those work as you are using the original list. Imagine the order of the second list is random. How do you make it in order without using the original list. It is possible as the resulting numbers are the only result of the original list.

Comment: @AspenGrey: I cannot make any sense out of what you are saying, and I am starting to suspect that any attempt to clear this up would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Direct transformation might be described by formula

```
3 + (A[i] + 3 * i) % 9
```

where `i` is index in the list

and backward one:

```
3 + (C[i] + 3 -  3 * i) % 9
```

Python code to check:

```
A = [3,3,6,9,6,6,3,9]
C = [6,9,6,3,3,6,6,6]

CC = [3 + (A[i] + 3 * i)%9 for i in range(len(A))]
print(C)
print(CC)

AA = [3 + (C[i] + 3 -  3 * i)%9 for i in range(len(A))]
print(A)
print(AA)

[6, 9, 6, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 9, 6, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6]

[3, 3, 6, 9, 6, 6, 3, 9] #original
[3, 3, 6, 9, 6, 6, 3, 9] #result
```